# Android not getting past serverSocket.accept();

Tags: android, sockets

I am currently trying to open a socket in android, but my code keeps sticking at one sentence.

```
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  private Socket clientSocket;
  private PrintWriter out;
  private BufferedReader in;

  public void run(){
    Log.i("DebugMessage", "ServerThread received pulse. Trying to open socket now!");
    try{
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(25555);
      Log.i("DebugMessage", "serverSocket is open, waiting for the clientSocket.");
      clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
      Log.i("DebugMessage", "serverSocket and clientSocket are both open! Waiting for in-/output!");

      in = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

      String input = in.readLine();
      out.println("received: " + input);

      in.close();
      out.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.i("DebugMessage", "Failed to open socket!");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

At `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` it keeps sticking.
Now I have seen this question a few other times, but the answers given were totally different. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107258/serversocket-android) is being said that it is about his code, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032482/serversocket-accept-not-accepting-connections-on-android) is being said that the problem is with the emulator. Now my question is, is my problem with the emulator or my code, and if it is with my code, how is it possible to fix it?

By the way, I have added these lines to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: As FD_ points out it won't go any further without an incoming connection.  So how, and from what, are your attempting to initiate a connection to it?  Also your summary of the second link it quite inaccurate, you really should re-read that one and understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerSocket.accept()` waits until a device connects to the socket's port (25555 in your case) on your device's ip address. It will only proceed and return a `Socket` when there is a new connection.

You'll find more information in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of FD_ is correct but i want to clarify it a bit. `accept()` calls `wait()`. So the thread will wait for a connection.
**You may want to call such code from a other thread.**